# Table Valued Parameter vs. large XML document: speeding up record existence check

Tags: sql-server, xml, performance, table-valued-parameters

I have an app that needs to check whether certain records it's receiving have already been processed.  Doing this requires comparing six fields in the input to corresponding columns in the database.

There are about 100,000 records per run, and the database table to which they are being compared has about 2 million records.  I expect to discard about 90% of the records after this check.

I created a proof-of-concept and wrote a stored procedure that received a large XML document, shredded it using the `nodes` function, and did an EXISTS check.  This took only a few seconds for a few thousand records, but takes seven minutes (against a development database) for 100,000.

It looks as if the bulk of the time is taken up by the database's struggles with the XML, but I can't be certain due to limited access to performance tools on this server.

It's a batch program and seven minutes wouldn't kill us, but I'd like it to be better.

So I'm wondering whether a TVP would be significantly faster.

The key word is "significantly":  there would likely be some obstacles to using a TVP in this environment, and I'd need to show a performance improvement of an order of magnitude to be persuasive.

A number of people have asked TVP vs. XML questions here before, and I've looked at them, but most of them seem to be about passing large numbers of records for insert.  So I'm not sure whether the reported performance improvement comes from not having to shred XML, or from fewer INSERT statements.

I don't intend to insert anything:  I just need to pass 100,000 six-part keys to the database, and return those keys that don't already exist.

Has anyone had experience with this scenario?

Comment: Okay. I am a newbie and I find this interesting. If you don't mind, can you please answer my questions ? Firstly, what do you mean by "a record is processed". Are the incoming records stored in a XML doc or in sql server ? Do you have a PK for the database table ? If you have the PK, can your app store the processed PK somewhere so that you only have to compare one 
column instead of a 6 ?

Comment: Hi, @BoratSagdiyev.  When I mean "a record is processed", I mean that records are retrieved from a different system, business logic is applied, and ultimately a subset of records are transformed and stored in the SQL database I am querying.  I do have a PK for the destination database server, but the incoming records don't know that PK because they come from a different system.  Storing the PK in the other system is not an option. Thanks.

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev Oh, and the incoming records arrive as a long string of XML, returned by a web service. The application that has to assess and store them is written in C#.

Comment: Obviously, I cannot help here. Please try the MSDN forums too. It has many famous developers too. At the same time, consider putting a huge bounty on this to attract more attention. Chenqui.

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev  As it has turned out, running the app while connected to the internal network produced run times of under 30 seconds.  When I wrote the question I was connected via VPN and experiencing 7 minute run times.  (Since the app was running on my dev machine, all network I/O was over VPN.)  So the "issue" is no longer an issue (although I'd still like to know the answer.)  Thanks for your comments!

Comment: If your data comes in as xml anyway, then I guess the overhead of converting that to a table valued parameter would probably be higher then the time that you might save on your stored procedure. You should also take into consideration that a table udt can have a primary key, that can speed up the execution of the select statement.

Comment: @ZoharPeled  Thanks for the additional information and ideas.

Comment: Shred it into a table variable, and put PK and/or unique constraints on it (because that creates indexes). If you do that then there will be no speed difference because you will be using a table variable either way - then it's down to the query.